# Navigate folders in explorer navigation pane with arrow keys

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, keyboard-navigation

One upon a time, if you put your focus in the navigation pane and navigated the folders with your arrow keys, it would update the folder contents view on the right. It was very useful for **visually** scanning the folders for whatever reason. Windows doesn't do that any more. How do I enable this?

Comment: On Windows 7, this is still possible to pressing Enter after changing the selected folder.

Comment: @drudge I was aware that you can press enter after moving the selection, but I was hoping to not need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of navigation pane has changed since then and now you need to press Enter to update the view on the right (as @drudge stated). There is no easy way to change this.